# How to start Outlook with Python and win32com

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, office-automation, com-automation

I manage to open Outlook Elements like mails or task with this code:

```
import win32com.client as win32

outlook = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application')
new_mail = outlook.CreateItem(4)
new_mail.Display(True)
```

And its possible to open Excel with this code:

```
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True
```

But how can I just open the main window of outlook? Can't find any functions or numbers for the "createItem" to just open the normal outlook window.

Someone got ideas?

I tried to search throu the MS VBA Api but couldnt find any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/outapp-createobjectoutlookapplication-but/0686ea7b-8bf0-45ee-8581-b1144b321299), one option might be:

```
outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(6).Display()
```

where `6` corresponds to the inbox as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oldefaultfolders).

Answer (score 0):

You need to display an `Explorer` window of Outlook. The [Explorers.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorers.add) method creates a new instance of the explorer window, then you just need to call the [Explorer.Display](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.display) method which displays a new `Explorer` object for the folder. The `Display` method is supported for explorer and inspector windows for the sake of backward compatibility. To activate an explorer or inspector window, use the [Activate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.activate(method)) method instead. Here is the sample VBA code which opens a new explorer window for the Drafts folder in Outlook:

```
Sub DisplayDrafts() 
 Dim myExplorers As Outlook.Explorers 
 Dim myOlExpl As Outlook.Explorer 
 Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set myExplorers = Application.Explorers 
 Set myFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts) 
 
 Set myOlExpl = myExplorers.Add(myFolder, olFolderDisplayNoNavigation) 
 
 myOlExpl.Display  
End Sub
```

The Outlook object model is common for all programming languages, so I think you will find the sequence of property and method calls that should be used to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

To start Outlook application, try `os.startfile("outlook")` or see example

```
import psutil
import os


class Outlook:
    @staticmethod
    def is_outlook_running():
        for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']):
            if p.info['name'] == "OUTLOOK.EXE":
                print("Yes", p.info['name'], "is running")
                break
        else:
            print("No, Outlook is not running")
            os.startfile("outlook")
            print("Outlook is starting now...")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    outlook = Outlook()
    outlook.is_outlook_running()
```